# Does "Property" in C# cost much?

Tags: code-quality, source-code, singleton, properties

I have a class created in some namespace, like `SomeNameSpace.SubNameSpace.StaticClassName`

Here is a code snippet from other code file where I want to use this class many more times, so I created a property in the code file like this

```
//Just to provide an Alias for long name "SomeNameSpace.SubNameSpace.StaticClassName.PropertyName"
public StaticClassName ServerProxyAlias
{
    get
    {
        return SomeNameSpace.SubNameSpace.Instance.PropertyName;
    }
    set
    {
        SomeNameSpace.SubNameSpace.Instance.PropertyName = value;
    }
}
```

**Is there any problem in doing like this ?**

Comment: Can't you just put a some sort of alias (e.g., in C# it would be `using SomeNameSpace.SubNameSpace`) at the top of any files that need the property (and that are outside of SomeNameSpace.SubNameSpace) and then use `StaticClassName.PropertyName` ?

Comment: are you aware about [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter "what's this?") aka "Don't talk to strangers"? _The fundamental notion is that a given object should assume as little as possible about the structure or properties of anything else (including its subcomponents)...._

Comment: Don't see any reason as to why this should be down voted. Although I really don't like the question I will +1 to compensate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's about consistency as much as readability. Other developers may miss the fact that you implemented a "proxy property" and still refer to `SomeNameSpace.SubNameSpace.Instance.PropertyName` directly.

Then you end up with code where sometimes `ServerProxyAlias` is used and sometimes isn't - even in the same method - and it's not obvious they're the same thing, lest one actually looks up how `ServerProxyAlias` is implemented.

I'm not saying it's a major problem, but you ask about any problems with your approach. Well, that's one that comes to my mind.

Answer (score 2):

Referring the question in the title, it costs you as much as invoking a method does. Java's equivalent of properties for example would be getters and setters.

Answer (score 2):

So you are creating a class for the sole purpose of being able to use a shorter name? Don't you have enough classes in your system already? Good software developers work hard to make their system easier to understand. You seem to be working hard to make it more convoluted and difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem with this code whatsoever.

As long as the actual `PropertyName` doesn't invoke a long running process then it should be OK.

However, you should really access the property directly. I don't see what the problem is with using the full name.

Comment: Problem comes when we change the Name or Namespace, however we can do a Re-factoring using VS. And also there will Long names seen in the code which disturbs me :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, it will **not make difference**. Because once code is compiled into IL it will have almost same hit on performance. Maybe there would be only minor (nano-seconds) difference in compile time.